# Making the font-size the max that can fit inside of its parent div

Tags: html, css, font-size

I want to have the text inside of a div to basically be the max height/size that could even fit inside of the div.  Is this possible without JS?

Comment: You need JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want it to fill it's parent div, then you mean dynamic. When there is dynamism, either you should use relative CSS (elastic, or fluid CSS; em and en sizes or percentages), or you should use JavaScript.

So, the answer to your question is clear. You can do that, but you should use `relative CSS measurement units`. In other words, you should use `%`, `em`, and stuff like that.